# Google Spreadsheet - modify other cell

Tags: google-spreadsheets

Is it possible for cell A1 to modify the contents or properties of cell B1?

For example: Change text or background color

Comment: Use conditional formatting on cell B1, based on a condition in cell A1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can create a conditional formatting rule on cell `B1` with conditions related to the content of cell `A1`.